# Azure Devops Pipelines - Xcode project with multiple provisioning profiles fails archive and sign

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to DevOps so please go easy on me if I've missed something basic :)

I’m using the following in Azure Pipelines: Hosted MacOS with an Xcode Build Agent (Xcode Version 5.142.0)

I've just started trying to set up a pipeline for an Xcode based project which uses multiple provisioning profiles.  In my scenario I have profiles for the following in my app:

- Intents
- ItentsUI
- Widget
- App

I've followed the instructions for setting up certs and provisioning profiles here **(although my project uses automatic signing)**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=vsts&tabs=apple-install-during-build

These are being installed correctly to a hosted build agent (no errors) and the build is proceeding perfectly until signing.

During signing it seems that the none of the targets can find their provisioning profiles (both when using 'manual' and 'automatic' assignment).

Here's what is run in the logs:

`[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace /Users/vsts/agent/2.142.1/work/1/s/*MYAPP**.xcworkspace -scheme **MYAPP** archive -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -archivePath /Users/vsts/agent/2.142.1/work/1/s/**MYAPP** CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual PROVISIONING_PROFILE= PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER= | /usr/local/bin/xcpretty --no-color`

Then later when it comes to archiving the following occurs for each scheme:

`error: "xxx Today Widget" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and App Groups features. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor. (in target 'xxx Today Widget')`

A few questions:

1. Is there an updated guide anyone can point me to? This seems like a common use case and I'm obviously missing something.
2. Alternatively is there a way to force which profile gets used for which scheme when archiving and signing multiple schemes in the same build?
3. Is automatic signing an option in pipelines?

For completeness I've seen what looks like a somewhat similar issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/964 but it's been closed for more than two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out after closer inspection the development certificate I had been using was the wrong one (there were a few on my Mac). I swapped this for the appropriate version and the issues went away.

I can now successfully build, archive and sign.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm having a similar problem and am wondering if I can get more information on your setup. Do you only have one Xcode task? And do you have the Signing style set to Automatic or Manual for the Xcode task? Do you have a Install Apple provisioning profile task for every profile that you need (it looks like maybe four in your case) or did you just install all of the profiles manually on the build agent? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @cmour I have one Xcode task and the signing style is set to "project defaults".  I needed to install of the provisioning profiles used by the app yes (temporary keychain using secured storage on the default mac build agent).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Lombard. Do you install the provisioning profiles using the "Install Apple Provisioning Profile" task in Azure Devops or did you just install the profiles on the build machine manually? I'm using the task in Azure Devops and I'm not having success with the build being able to find the profiles.

Comment: @cmour - I'm using the "Install Apple Provisioning Profile" step but you need to have the profiles set up in "Secure Files" so that the pipeline can get them as part of the build process. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What type of provisioning profile did you use in order to work? And if you used default as parameter for signing in Xcode@5 what were your project settings?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how we got building an iOS app with multiple provisioning profiles to work in Azure DevOps.

- Ensure you have the [Apple App Store Azure DevOps extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store&targetId=a575c211-7cc4-4523-939f-a1691bf34fa2&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) written by Microsoft installed in your account.
- Install all of the provisioning profiles that are needed using multiple [Install Apple Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops) tasks
- Add the [Xcode build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode-build?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) and configure it with your workspace/project settings
- Set the "Signing style" to "Automatic signing" and provide your team ID in the "Team ID" field under the "Signing & provisioning" section
- Create a .plist file, configure it similar to the following, and put it somewhere (your code repository, secure files, etc). This example is of a watch app, but could be any scenario where multiple provisioning profiles are necessary. You can find a provisioning profile's UUID by opening it in a text editor and looking for the "UUID" key.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
        <dict>
            <key>YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.watchkitapp.watchkitextension</key>
            <string>UUID_OF_ASSOCIATED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE</string>
            <key>YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.watchkitapp</key>
            <string>UUID_OF_ASSOCIATED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE</string>
            <key>YOUR_BUNDLE_ID</key>
            <string>UUID_OF_ASSOCIATED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>signingCertificate</key>
        <string>iOS Distribution</string>
        <key>signingStyle</key>
        <string>manual</string>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>app-store</string>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>YOUR_TEAM_ID</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

- Under the "Package options" section, specify "Plist" in the "Export options" field and provide a path to the .plist you created in the "Export options plist" field

Comment: I've had no luck getting this to work. All I get is: "No profiles for '<MY_BUNDLE_ID_1>' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '<MY_BUNDLE_ID_1>'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target '<MY_EXTENSION_TARGET>' from project '<MY_PROJECT>')". And passing the -allowProvisioningUpdates gets me back to the old "There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode" :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to correctly target your Project's `.xcworkspace` file instead of letting it default to `<Project Name>.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace`. This haunted me for two days while testing.

Example:

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/<Project Name>.xcworkspace' # Make sure this line is here
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: default, 10, 9, 8, specifyPath
    exportPath: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/$(configuration)'
```