# Does azure devops support ios automatic code signing?

Tags: ios, azure-devops, devops, code-signing, xcodebuild

It seems like this would be a yes or no answer, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=azure-devops&tabs=apple-install-during-build) is  not clear at all. It actually references `xcode 8` so it's a little out dated. What I seem to be able to piece together is that you can make it work for `ad hoc` builds by copying the automatically created provisioning profile along with the certs used to sign it. If you want it to work fully with  automatic signing you need to use your own build agent, per this [azure-devops-docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7302)

Does anyone know what the current state of the `azure-devops` documentation is in regards to code signing for an iOS app are?

There is  some mention of this for [Team Foundation Server 2017...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/secure-certs?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

The documentation leans to manual signing, which is not what Apple recommends, no right or wrong, I just want to know if automatic signing can be used!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does azure devops support ios automatic code signing?

I think the answer is Yes. As I know the [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) has `signingOption` input which supports `Automatic signing`, is it what you're looking for?

[image]

And you can choose the version of Xcode to use depending on your needs:

[image]

Ps: If you're using self-hosted agent with azure devops service, or you're using TFS/Azure Devops Server. You should install the correct version yourself and specify path to find the xcode.

Here's [one detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634755/10910450) from **Keith Clark** about how to build an iOS app with multiple provisioning profiles in Azure DevOps with `Automatic signing` style. You may get some help from this issue.

Comment: Multiple provisioning profile on automatic signing is not working , any idea ?