# Azure Devops Pipelines - Xcode project with multiple provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, azure-devops, app-store, provisioning-profile

I have configured pipeline to build an iOS app that is also an AUv3 plugin, it requires two provisioning profiles but I can't manage the Plist to allow the signature for both.

I have installed .p12 and Apple Provisioning Profiles.

This is my Xcode task:

```
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode build'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: iphoneos13.7
    xcWorkspacePath: ‘project_name/project.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'project_name - All'
    packageApp: true
    exportPath: output/
    exportOptions: plist
    exportOptionsPlist: ‘file.plist'
    signingOption: auto
    teamId: [10-character development team ID]
    useXcpretty: false
```

And here is my .plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>provisioningProfiles</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.company.product_name</key>
    <string>UUID_Code</string>
    <key>com.company.product_name.product_nameAUv3</key>
    <string>UUID_Code</string>   
</dict>
<key>signingCertificate</key>
<string>iOS Distribution</string>
<key>signingStyle</key>
<string>manual</string>
<key>method</key>
<string>app-store</string>
<key>teamID</key>
<string>**********</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but Xcode project with multiple provisioning profiles fails archive and sign:

```
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.company.product_name.product_nameAUv3' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.company.product_name.product_nameAUv3'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 13.7'
```

Someone have similar setup? This seems I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi @amdev1, Could you please check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225705/azure-devops-pipelines-xcode-project-with-multiple-provisioning-profiles-fails) and then share the result here? According to the error message, it need you enable the feature Automatic signing, but we can see that you have enable it in the YAML build

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT! I have enabled automatic signing, but it doesn't solve my issue. I'll share my result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225705/azure-devops-pipelines-xcode-project-with-multiple-provisioning-profiles-fails)

Comment: Hi @amdev1, you can free feel to share the result here and we will check it and help you.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?